# Shortcut for "Convert java code ( not file) to Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

In Android studio, When you copy java code to Kotlin file, you see a dialog

[image]

I need help to know if I select "Don't show dialog" how can i re-enabled it. I can't find settings in studio unfortunately :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> (Mac) or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> in Windows and Linux to invoke find action dialogue.

Type **convert pasted java code**

[image]

If it is *off*, press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

**@aristotll's answer gives you what you want!**

If you want to convert an existing file:
- Menu: `Code > Convert Java File to Kotlin File`
- Win: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>
- Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>